# Expression must be a pointer to a complete object type when cast void pointer

Tags: c

I'm trying to do function remove extension of a name is type wchar_t or char, inside for() i cast void pointer to type wchar_t or char, then there was an error:

> Expression must be a pointer to a complete object type.

Here is sample code to show an instance of the issue by itself.

```
int RemoveExtension(
    void    *p_str,     /*  Name                        */
    bool    isWchar     /*  true：wchar_t, false：char　*/
) {
    int ii, len;

    // Get length
    len = (isWchar) ? wcslen( (wchar_t *)p_str ) : strlen( (char *)p_str );

    // Remove extension
    /*　wchar_t　*/
    if( isWchar ) {

        for( ii = 0; ii < len; ii++ ) {
            if( L'.' == (wchar_t *)p_str[ii] ) {  //Error here
                (wchar_t *)p_str[ii] = L'\0';     //Error here
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    /*　char　*/
    else {

        for( ii = 0; ii < len; ii++ ) {
            if( '.' == (char *)p_str[ii]) {       //Error here
                (char *)p_str[ii] = '\0';         //Error here
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm not understanding what this error is trying to say. There is no object or struct here.

Comment: `(wchar_t *)p_str[ii]` -> `((wchar_t *)p_str)[ii]` -- see http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: "*There is no object or struct here.*" <- there is. Whatever your `void *` points to is an *object* in the terms of C. But `void` is an incomplete type, so your compiler doesn't know the size and therefore can't do indexing. The indexing has higher precedence than the cast. Use parantheses to first cast to a complete type and indexing will work.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: I understand. Thank you very much. Exactly!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know why you get exactly that error, but according to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) table
expression

`(wchar_t *)p_str[ii]` is `(wchar_t *)(p_str[ii])`

not `((wchar_t *)p_str)[ii]`,

probably it's not what you want

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much. +1

Answer (score 8):

To understand the error message, you have to know two things:

1. Any value having a type stored somewhere is called an *object* in C. Your variables identify objects, your pointers (should) point to objects.
2. Types in C can be complete or incomplete. The distinction is that for *complete* types, the size of an object of that type is known. For *incomplete* types, it is unknown. Without knowing the size, e.g. indexing isn't possible because you need the size to calculate the offset of the next array element. `void` is a special case of an *incomplete type*: it can't ever be completed, because it's unknown (`void *` is the *generic pointer type* and may point to an object of *any type*).

So, your compiler just tells you that `p_str[ii]` is invalid because you attempt to index on a pointer of type `void *`.

---

The source of the problem is simple: indexing has a higher precedence than casting, therefore just use parantheses to solve this problem:

```
((wchar_t *)p_str)[ii]
```